# How to wrap text in span tags except first word with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to wrap the last words in a string with span tags excluding the first word? So it'd be for example:

```
var string = 'My super text';
```

Becomes

```html
My <span>super text</span>
```

I have this:

```
var text = string.split(" ");

// drop the last word and store it in a variable
var last = text.pop();

// join the text back and if it has more than 1 word add the span tag
// to the last word
if (text.length > 0) {
   return text.join(" ") + " <span>" + last + "</span>";
}
else {
   return "<span>" + text.join(" ") + last + "</span>";
}
```

Which wraps the last word with span tags if it has at least two but not sure how to modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `text.shift()` which will return the first word, instead of `text.pop()` which returns the last word. Then it will be much easier to accomplish this.

```
var text= string.split(" ");

// get the first word and store it in a variable
var first = text.shift();

// join the text back and if it has more than 1 word add the span tag
// to the last word
if (text.length > 0) {
   return first + " <span>" + text.join(" ") + "</span>";
} else {
   return "<span>" + first + "</span>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a regular expression.

```
text = text.replace(/\s(.*)$/, ' <span>$1</span>');
```

However, you should probably turn the following into a recursive function...

```
$('body').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).each(function() {
    var node = this;
    // Normalise node.
    node.data = $.trim(node.data);

    node.data.replace(/\s+(.*)\s*$/, function(all, match, offset) {
        var chunk = node.splitText(offset);
        chunk.parentNode.removeChild(chunk);
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' ' + match));
        node.parentNode.appendChild(span);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wPaF/).

This will allow you to modify text nodes and insert the `span` elements without messing with serialised HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
var space = string.indexOf(' ');

if (space !== -1) {
   return string.slice(0,space) + " <span>" + string.slice( space ) + "</span>";
} else {
   return "<span>" + string + "</span>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to split the text, just check if there is a space, and insert a span there.

This code inserts a span after the first space, and if there is no space (idx == -1), the span is put at the beginning of the string:

```
var idx = string.indexOf(' ');
return string.substr(0, idx + 1) + "<span>" + string.substr(idx + 1) + "</span>";
```