# How to wrap the first word of a title with a span

Tags: javascript

I would like to achieve [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441045/how-to-wrap-text-in-span-tags-except-first-word-with-jquery), but to wrap first word of every `<h1>` tag with a `<span>` tags.  It should look like this:

```
 <h1><span>This</span> is a title</h1>
```

I quess it's doneable without a plugin...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JavaScript **[`String#repalce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method

```js
var tag = document.querySelector('h1');

tag.innerHTML = tag.innerHTML.replace(/^\s*\w+/, '<span style="color:red">$&</span>');
```

```html
<h1>This is a title </h1>
```

---

**FYI :** Since it recreates the inner elements it will destroy any handler attached to its descendant element.

---

**UPDATE :** In case you want to update all `h1` tag then you need to get all `h1` and iterate over them.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('h1')).forEach(function(ele) {
  ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML.replace(/^\s*\w+/, '<span style="color:red">$&</span>');
});
```

```html
<h1>This is a title </h1>
<h1>This is a title </h1>
<h1>This is a title </h1>
<h1>This is a title </h1>
<h1>This is a title </h1>
```

Comment: This will, of course, blow away any handlers or data attached to any descendant elements in the `h1` element by throwing them away and recreating them from scratch. Which is only a problem if it's a problem.

Comment: Great! could you explain to me, what `/^\s*\w+/` "is doing" in this code?

Comment: @Gallex :  it's regex to match the string at beginning https://regex101.com/r/pD1xJ3/1 - where `\s` for space character and `\w` for word character

Answer (score 0):

Sincerely, that task was very difficult! Great Question!
By the way, I think that an acceptable solution could be what follows:
I replaced all first word of h1 tag without loosing listeners...
Hope it helps!

```js
function WrapFirstH1WordCtrl() {
  let titles = this.querySelectorAll("h1");
  let test = this.getElementById('test');
  
  test.onclick = () => console.log("HELLO GUYS");
  
  
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(titles, (title) => {
    let value = title.firstChild.nodeValue;
    let t = /^(\w+)/.exec(value).pop();
    let span = this.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = t || "";
    
    title.firstChild.nodeValue = value.replace(t, "")
    title.insertBefore(span, title.firstChild);
    
  });
  
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', WrapFirstH1WordCtrl.bind(document))
```

```css
span {
  background: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<h1>foo 1 <button id="test">HELLO AND KEEP LISTENERS</button></h1>
<h1>foo 2</h1>
<h1>foo 3</h1>
<h1>foo 4</h1>
<h1>foo 5</h1>
<h1>foo 6</h1>
<h1>foo 7</h1>
<h1>foo 8</h1>
<h1>foo 9</h1>
<h1>foo 10</h1>
<h1>foo 11</h1>
<h1>foo 12</h1>
<h1>foo 13</h1>
<h1>foo 14</h1>
<h1>foo 15</h1>
<h1>foo 16</h1>
<h1>foo 17</h1>
<h1>foo 18</h1>
<h1>foo 19</h1>
<h1>foo 20</h1>
<h1>foo 21</h1>
<h1>foo 22</h1>
<h1>foo 23</h1>
<h1>foo 24</h1>
<h1>foo 25</h1>
<h1>foo 26</h1>
<h1>foo 27</h1>
<h1>foo 28</h1>
<h1>foo 29</h1>
<h1>foo 30</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be an option. Not very elegant but should do the job. If i am not mistaking this should only effect the first `textNode` of the `h1` element. The rest is just inserting the created `span` before the existing elements, not affecting descendant elements. Correct me if i am wrong. ;)

```js
var titles = document.querySelectorAll('.title');

titles.forEach(function(e) {
  var childNodes = [].slice.call(e.childNodes),
      txtContent = childNodes.shift().textContent, 
      span;
  e.childNodes[0].textContent = '';
  txtContent.split(' ').forEach(function(s, i) {
    if(i > 0) {
      e.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(" " + s), e.children[1]);
    } else {
      span = document.createElement('span');
      span.textContent = s;
      e.insertBefore(span, e.firstChild);
    }
  })
})
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}

.baz {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Hello World</h1>
<h1 class="title">Hello Foo Bar <span class="baz">Baz</span></h1>
```