# How to change the size of the first two words of <p> tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

I want to target the first two words of a paragraph using javascript and change their size.

**for example:**

```
<p>My name is muhammad hamd</p>
```

Here I just want to target 'My name', the first two words of the `p` tag, and change their size.

Comment: What do you mean by "target"? Select them as nodes? Get them and store them in a variable? Please be specific, and do *not* add more tags than needed.

Comment: @InSync yes want to selet them as nodes anf change there size

Comment: How are you defining a word? e.g. are each of the first two words always followed by a single space? Once you've found them you'll need to change the content of p so those two words are wrapped for example in a span element so you can apply CSS to them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wrap the first word of a title with a span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672753/how-to-wrap-the-first-word-of-a-title-with-a-span)

Comment: or [Select first 2 words with jQuery and wrap them with <span> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182113/select-first-2-words-with-jquery-and-wrap-them-with-span-tag)

Answer (score 0):

See comments inline:

```js
// First get a reference to the element
const p = document.querySelector("p");

// Then get the text content of the element
let text = p.textContent;

// Take that string and break it up (at the spaces) into an array
//   Here the // denotes a regular expression
//   the \s is the JavaScript escape code for space
//   the + indicates that it can be one or more spaces in a row
//   the g at the end means look through the entire string
let words = text.split(/\s+/g);

// Extract just the first two words
console.log(words[0], words[1]);
```

```html
<p>My name is muhammad hamd</p>
```

The steps can be combined for more concise code:

```js
// Extract just the first two words
let words = document.querySelector("p").textContent.split(/\s+/g)
console.log(words[0], words[1]);
```

```html
<p>My name is muhammad hamd</p>
```